# Found error in answer, cannot edit or comment

Tags: support

A situation came up today where I found an answer that is definitely correct, but there is a small typographical error in the answer that would cause the application to fail if copied verbatim. I do not have the rep to comment, and I cannot edit the other person's answer because the typo is 1 character, and apparently 1 character edits are not allowed. What can I do in this situation?

Here is the question/answer [Why does SelectSingleNode return null object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31684468/why-does-selectsinglenode-return-null-object)

In the answer from djs the error is in the code snippet: $metas = xml should be $metas = $xml. If someone wants to fix it. The only way I could satisfy the 6 character threshold would be adding pointless text which I believe is in bad form.

Comment: Is there anything else in the post that can be fixed? Spelling, grammar, less bold?

Comment: You could also link the answer here to have someone with higher rep edit it. It isn't necessary to flag this for moderator attention. As @Andy said, are you sure there's nothing else you could do to meet the 6-character edit minimum?

Comment: fwiw, I fixed it just now.

Comment: can't turn around without getting downvoted around here. I guess next time I'll just ignore any errors I find.

Comment: You're just in the limbo portion of a new users Stack Overflow experience. This portion is designed to slow down the spammers. Once you reach 50 rep you can start commenting (what this would be a good situation for) or you can suggest and edit. But no, there is no way to get around the minimum character requirement until you get to 2000 rep, when your edits will no longer need five other users to review them.

Comment: thanks for the useful comments. I'll get the hang of this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could fix the typo and in addition:

- Put a comment after the line you fixed stating you fixed the typo. (i.e. comment the line of code you fixed)
- Correct other typos or spelling mistakes, grammar, etc.
- Add potential missing tags.
- Change the formating by putting some titles or headers in bold or something similar.